# Rspec Views : No route matches using wrong controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, routes

I have a view of a book that I want to test.
I render it in my browser via `http://..../books/1`

Here is the error I get when I'm running Rspec:

```
1) books/show should display the book name
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
     No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"books"}
```

Here is my test using [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl):

```
RSpec.describe "books/show", type: :view do
  before(:each) do
    @book = FactoryGirl.create(:book)
    render
  end

  it "should display the book name" do
    rendered.should contain(@book.name)
  end
end
```

I think I found the error but I don't understand it.

In my `routes.rb` file I have `resources :books`

If I do a rake routes in my console, I get:

```
...
books       GET      /books(.:format)                              books#index
            POST     /books(.:format)                              books#create
new_book    GET      /books/new(.:format)                          books#new
edit_book   GET      /books/:id/edit(.:format)                     books#edit
book        GET      /books/:id(.:format)                          books#show
            PATCH    /books/:id(.:format)                          books#update
            PUT      /books/:id(.:format)                          books#update
            DELETE   /books/:id(.:format)                          books#destroy
...
```

Why is there a difference in my routes between `book` and `bookS` ? I guess that is why the error is raised.

The show action is only present for the controller `book`, not `bookS`.

Comment: Well try `render @book` or `render book_path(@book)` and let me know :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit No more success :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @PeterAlfvin suggested, the error was in my view.
In my controller I set some variables related to the `book` but I was assuming (and now I understand why it is not) that the controller was called during the test view and that it should have been set those variable during the test.

So for each variables called in my view, I created a assign line and everything works now.

```
assign(:my_variable, MY_VALUE)
```

The original error was raised because I was rendering a `link_to` with a `nil` URL.

Answer (score 0):

A `books` controller is indeed a different controller than a `book` controller.

Your routes show that you have the traditional `show` route in the books controller, but note that it requires that an `id` parameter be present. Your template must have tried to invoke the `show` action with a `get` operation on `/books` without specifying an id.

If you show your template code, we can confirm.

Comment: Not sure I understand, instead of calling `render` I should call `get 'books/my_id'` ? Because I'm getting the error `undefined method 'get' for #<RSpec::ExampleGroups`

Comment: No, your render is fine.  I was saying I believe it's a problem with your template (e.g. some link contained there) and suggesting you post that code so we could take a look.

Comment: You were right, it was related to that, I will post my answer to see if it's a normal behavior.